# If statement not working using a nested relationship field

Tags: relationships, conditionals, grid

I am having a bit of trouble with a relationshop field nested inside a grid.

I have the following data structure.

```
|-Products
|--product_where_to_buy (relationship field for partners)

|-Partners
|--partner_retail_urls (grid field)
|----product (relationship field with products)
|----url (url to purchase page)
```

What I want to do is filter the partner retail urls by product but it doesn't work no matter what I try.

This returns all results.

```
{product_where_to_buy status="open|closed"}
    {product_where_to_buy:partner_retail_urls search:product:title="product name"}
        <li><a href="{product_where_to_buy:partner_retail_urls:url}">{product_where_to_buy:title}</li>
    {/product_where_to_buy:partner_retail_urls}
{/product_where_to_buy}
```

This crashes the template parser

```
{product_where_to_buy status="open|closed"}
    {product_where_to_buy:partner_retail_urls}
        {if product_where_to_buy:partner_retail_urls:product:title == "product name"}
        <li><a href="{product_where_to_buy:partner_retail_urls:url}">{product_where_to_buy:title}</li>
        {/if}
    {/product_where_to_buy:partner_retail_urls}
{/product_where_to_buy}
```

Error

```
You have an invalid conditional in your template. Please review your conditionals for an unclosed string, invalid operators, a missing }, or a missing {/if}.

Parser State: Unexpected ‘href’ (VARIABLE); expected RD in Template “products/index” on line 3.
```

Am I missing something or am i just going about it the wrong way?

Answer (score -1):

It looks as if your code is missing the closing `</a>` tag.

Comment: Correct it's missing, but that won't cause a parse issue.